# Creating database file in application data

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite, fileoutputstream, android-assets

I read similar questions and answers, but none working for me.
I am trying copying sqlite database from **assets** folder to **application** data folder, but this always fail, because target database file is not created.

*TRY 1:*

```
databasePath = context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/test.db";

Path path = Paths.get(databasePath);

OutputStream applicationDatabaseStream = Files.newOutputStream(path, StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.WRITE);
```

Fails with exception:

`W/System.err: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /data/user/0/eu.example.test/databases/test.db`

*TRY 2:*

```
databasePath = context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/test.db";

OutputStream applicationDatabaseStream = new FileOutputStream(databasePath);
```

Fails with exception:

`W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/user/0/eu.example.test/databases/test.db: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)`

Whats wrong with this code?

I expect that code create file in application data folder.

Comment: You should first check if the directory exists. And if not create the directory before you try to put a file in a non existent directory.

Comment: Ok. But this not create directory if not exists?

Comment: No, if you create a file in a non-existent directory the directly will not be created. You can check if the directory exists using [Android Studio Device Explorer](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/device-file-explorer).

Comment: Ok. My fail, i checked that directory not exists using device explorer, but I assume that entire path will be created if not exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't create a path like that.  `context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/test.db";`  The dataDir will exist, but nobody has yet created the databases subdirectory.  So it won't exist, which means opening test.db will fail.  You have to create the entire directory tree first.